# rsyslog to fluentd via ssl

Tags: rsyslog, fluentd

I have been configuring to send data from rsyslog to fluentd via ssl.

I have installed `secure_forward` plugin in fluentd. This config is as below.

**Fluentd config:**

```
<source>
  @type secure_forward
  shared_key qeu1223123ecdcdjs
  self_hostname myhostname.domain.com
  secure yes
  ca_cert_path /etc/fluentd/appcertificate.crt
  ca_private_key_path /etc/fluentd/ssl.key
  ca_private_key_passphrase passphrase
  bind myhostname.domain.com
  port 25114
  keepalive 3600
  tag system
 <server>
   @type syslog
   port 25143
   bind myhostname.domain.com
   tag system
   format none
 </server>
</source>
```

**rsyslog config**

```
$defaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/rsyslog.d/ca_cert.crt
$ActionSendStreamDriver gtls
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode x509/name
$ActionSendStreamDriverPermittedPeer *.domain.com
*.* @@myhostname.domain.com:25144
```

Can someone help if I am missing something. I dont know where to set `shared_key` in rsyslog config. Currently if I take `tcpdump` I see there is data coming but I don't see the same in output file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems not to be available a `shared_key` configuration in rsyslog.

I would give a try with certificate instead of a passphrase.

```
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/rsyslog.d/ca_cert.crt
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /etc/rsyslog.d/cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /etc/rsyslog.d/key.pem
```

I add the `tcpdump` command for completeness:

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 tcp port 25144 -X -s 0 -nn
```